# URL Rewrite Rule do a redirect but changes url in address bar

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

ok i have the following configuration below

```
RewriteRule ^skibe/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/skibe?sku=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now what i want here is..

when i type

> http://myhost.com/skibe/abc

it will be still the same on my address bar as  `http://myhost.com/skibe/abc`

but the problem is it keeps on changing to

> http://myhost.com/skibe?sku=abc

is there something wrong with my configuration? my rewrite directives are

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks 
   RewriteEngine on
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `http://%{HTTP_HOST}` part in your rule's target. That will cause mod_rewrite to inherently redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^skibe/(.*)$ /skibe?sku=$1 [QSA,L]
```